# Starting point for Creating CMS using .Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, content-management-system

i want to create CMS using asp.net that export only HTML Pages.who now starting point without using asp.net MCV?

Comment: Can i ask the reason why you dont want to use asp.net  MVC

Comment: because i'm not familiar with it also my page template has XML base structure for showing web contents. i think its to complicated do this in MVC

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use MVC then you should either use WebAPI, and do a html/js/css front end or asp.net web forms.

However I would recommend you look at [umbraco](http://umbraco.com/) an open source asp.net cms.